# iCloud sync phone contacts

Tags: iphone, icloud

How do I sync my phone contacts with icloud?
I will change my iphone so I need to sync my phone contacts on ICloud and then I want to recover the contacts on the new Iphone, what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings ---> iCloud ---> enable "contacts".
All your contacts will be save on iCloud. And every apple device with your Apple ID will have your contacts.